# Regex to find a newline character ("\n") and replace with empty string from address

Tags: ruby, regex, string

We have a string which contains address in it like below:

`"first-name, last-name, email, address\n Ashok, G, \"Hyderabad\nTelangana\n India\"\n John, M, \"Mayur Vihar\nNew Delhi\n110096, India\"\n"`

and the requirement is to replace all the newline characters ("\n") characters with "" from the address string only (inside \" \")

The Expected output should be like:

`"first-name, last-name, email, address\n Ashok, G, \"Hyderabad Telangana India\"\n John, M, \"Mayur Vihar, New Delhi 110096, India\"\n "`

Answer (score 0):

```
\\n(?=(?:(?!\\").)*\\"(?:(?:(?!\\").)*\\"(?:(?!\\").)*\\")*(?:(?!\\").)*$)
```

Try this.Replace by `empty string`.See demo.

https://www.regex101.com/r/rG7gX4/7

Comment: Sorry @vks it is not giving exact out put what i need(missing to replace in `\"heyderabad\nTelangana\n India\"` sub-string). Can you please rewrite regex to match all the \n and replace with space inside \" \".  Thanks.

Comment: it should be like `\"heyderabad Telangana India\"`,  but the out put in demo `"first-name, last-name, email, address\n Ashok, G, \"heyderabad\nTelangana\n India\"\n ABCD, L, \"GunturAP500505, India\"\n"`

Comment: If your regex were much longer you wouldn't be able to tweet it.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you do it as follows:

```
str.gsub(/(?<=\").*?(?=\")/) { |s| s.gsub(/\n/,' ') }
  #=> "first-name, last-name, email, address\n Ashok, G, \"heyderabad |
       Telangana  India\"  ABCD, L, \"Guntur AP 500505, India\"\n"
```

This matches each string bracketed by `\"`, which in turn is passed to the block for removal of all `\n`'s. `(?<=\")` is a positive lookbehind; `(?=\")` is a postive lookahead. `?` is needed to make `.*` non-greedy, so the match stops before the first matching postive lookahead.

This doesn't give quite the spacing contained in your desired output. That spacing seems somewhat inconsistent, however.  For example, where did the single space at the end of the string come from?  You said you wanted to replace `\n` between pairs of `\"`, but you didn't say what you want to replace it with.  (I assumed one space.)  If you want different spacing, you could adjust the regex used by `gsub` inside the block. For example, you might have `/\s*\n\s*/`.